# How to use Javascript to validate dynamically generated PHP form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I've created a form using PHP in which the user has to click on a radio button before clicking on the button to submit the form. It looks as follows:

```
<form name="films" action="showing.php" method="post">
<table id="filmtable">
<tr><th>Title</th><th>Length</th><th>Description</th><th>Poster</th><th>Required</th></tr>
<?php
//Loop through every row returned by $result query to display it in table.
while ($newArray = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $title  = $newArray['title'];
    $length = $newArray['length'];
    $description = $newArray['description'];
    $image = $newArray['image'];

    //Echo statements will display query results on screen.

    echo "<tr><td>$title</td><td>$length</td><td>$description</td>";
    echo "<td><image src=\"$image\"</td>";
    echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" id='wanted' name=\"wanted[]\" value='$title'></td></tr>";

}
// if (! array_key_exists($_POST['wanted[0]'], $result)){
//  echo "Select it.";
//}


?>
</table>
<input type="submit" onsubmit = 'return validate()' value="Select Film">
</form>
```

As a validation measure I created the following in Javascript with the aim of preventing the user from submitting the form if they have not selected a radio button:

```
<script>
function validate(){
    var radio = document.getElementById('wanted').checked;

    if(radio=="")
    {
        alert("Please select a film to continue making a booking.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}

</script>
```

The script prevents the user from submitting the form if no selection has been made from the radio boxes as intended. However, it will only allow the form to be submitted if the first radio box is selected. Selecting any button other than this one will cause the submit attempt to fail. What changes should I make to the JS to rectify this situation?

Comment: Do not use the same `ID` for all the radio buttons, `ID`'s should be unique. Create a `class` instead, hint: when using the `class` you will need to put all elements in an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This PHP fetch loop attributes multiple times the same id="wanted" to many radio buttons.
An Id should be unique.... So it's a bad practice.

Remove the id and add a class instead:

```
echo "<td><input type=\"radio\" class=\"wanted[]\" name=\"wanted[]\" value='$title'></td></tr>";
```

Then, the use of jQuery saves pain...

Within your submit script:

```
if(!$('.wanted').prop("checked")){
    alert("Please select a film to continue making a booking.");
    return;
}
```

Add this jQuery lib call in your head:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT** - See comments
Function validate should be this:

```
function validate(){
    var wantedChecked=$(".wanted:checked");
    if (!wantedChecked.prop("checked")){
        console.log("false");
        return false;

    }else{
        console.log("true");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't working either. Nothing happens, the form just submits.

Comment: Sorry... I just noticed the missing double quotes... within prop(). See edit

Comment: Now the alert just opens when the page loads. Once clicked away the form can be submitted without any input.

Comment: Hew.... Place that if statement within your submit script. For sure, if it executes onload, the alert will show.

Comment: Added a return, just in case your script would go on after the alert.

Comment: Could you demonstrate exactly what you mean by my submit script? I'm still having trouble getting this to work.

Comment: Well... Your validate() function is this submit script... Since triggered by the type="submit" button.

Comment: I've done what you said: the alert appears now. The form is always submitted, and the alert appears even when a radio button is selected.

Comment: If still not working... Hit the « automatically move this discussion to chat?» and I'll help you... I'M in the mood ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112840/discussion-between-madrigone-and-louys-patrice-bessette).

Answer (score 0):

`getElementById` returns the first element matching the selector. If you just want to verify that *any of them* were checked, you could do something like:

```
var anyChecked = document.querySelectorAll('[name=wanted]:checked').length > 0;
```

Comment: Tried your code and it doesn't work. Where should I place this in the JS script?

Comment: It works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/76cz8udk/2/. You should just need to replace your `var radio = document.getElementById('wanted').checked;` with what I posted, and change your condition from `if(radio=="")` to `if(!anyChecked)`